# =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH.... the difference between 1 and 11

Tags: excel

I am trying to convert a single column of numbers in excel to multiple depending on the content.

e.g. Table 1 contains 1 column that contains 1 or more numbers between 1 and 11 separated with a comma. Table 2 should contain 11 columns with a 1 or a 0 depending on the numbers found in Table 1.

I am using the following formula at present:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1",A2)),1,0)
```

The next column contains the following:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2",A2)),1,0)
```

All the way to 11

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("11",A2)),1,0)
```

The problem with this however is that the code for finding references to 1 also find the references to 11. Is it possible to write a formula that can tell the difference so that if I have the following in Table 1:

```
 2, 5, 11
```

It doesn't put a 1 in column 1 of Table 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use, for list with just comma:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",1,", ","&A2&",")),1,0)
```

If list is separated with `,` (comma+space):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", 1,", ", "&A2&",")),1,0)
```

Comment: Aargh, I was just typing this answer! If the number of spaces before/after each comma isn't consistent then you'll have to do some sort of cleanup on the contents of A2 e.g. using the TRIM and/or SUBSTITUTE functions.

Comment: @nekomatic Good point. Write your own answer dealing this concern!

Answer (score 2):

A version of LS_dev's answer that will cope with 0...n spaces before or after each comma is:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", 1 ,",", "&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A2,","," , "))&" ,")),1,0)
```

The SUBSTITUTE makes sure there's always at least one space before and after each comma and the TRIM replaces multiple spaces with one space, so the result of the TRIM function will have exactly one space before and after each comma.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `SUBSTITUTE` function to change all "11" to Roman numeral "XI" prior to doing your search:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1",SUBSTITUTE(A2, "11", "XI"))),1,0)
```

Comment: And what about "10"? ;-)

Comment: @nekomatic, good point!  Would need to add another SUBSTITUTE function, or just use LS_dev solution, which is better, I think.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to eliminate "11" case, but this is all based on hardcoded values, there should be a smarter solution.

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AND("1",NOT("11")),A2)),1,0)

Comment: This is not a smarter solution. `AND()` returns a boolean (true or false) and will always return an error in your case.

Comment: That doesn't work. It searches A4 for the result of AND("1",NOT("11")) which is #VALUE.

Comment: if you have a cell with 2,5,11 (I did not care if it will be A4 or A2 or A3455) it will return 0 - just tested. maybe I misunderstood the task. behaves same as this one: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",11,", ","&A2&",")),1,0) if I remove the comma. So would appriciate if you would point me to the failing case so that I can understand what was wrong

Comment: @Jerry by there should be a smarter solution I wanted to say that there should be a better solution than mine :)